# On Hover Menu List Items Disalign

Tags: html, css, onhover

I am using simple HTML and CSS to create horizontal menu using unordered list.

This is HTML & CSS code:

```css
.nav_bar{
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav_bar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav_bar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.nav_bar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav_bar ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #ff6600;
    transition: width .4s;
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solution</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know where is the problem and why it is occurring?
Please help me out with good reason..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive fixed your code and ive got something like this.

```
.nav_bar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: orange;
    position: relative;
}

.nav_bar ul li a::after{
       content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 4px;
    background: #ff6600;
    transition: width .4s;
    width: 0;
}
```

the problem is your `after` element is displayed `inline-block` so it rendered inline with your achor tag. and since your achor tag doesnt have enough width to display the `::after` inline, your `::after` element wrapped after your anchor tag. 
see this: https://jsfiddle.net/pm68Lzmv/

Comment: Im glad it helped you @SameerMoin

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add `position:absolute;` to `:after` selector for a tag

Remove `margin-left` from `.nav_bar` and add `right:0`

```css
.nav_bar{        
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}

.nav_bar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav_bar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.nav_bar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #aaa;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.nav_bar ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #ff6600;
    transition: width .4s;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);    
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solution</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: when i add this line (position:absolute;) on nav_bar:after it become more unstable

Comment: i use margin to align my div on right side if i remove this margin it will float on left side

Answer (score 0):

Remove .nav_bar{ margin-left:0px}

Add .nav_bar ul li a position:relative;

add .nav_bar ul li a:after position:absolute;

```css
.nav_bar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav_bar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #aaa;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.nav_bar ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #ff6600;
    transition: width .4s;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);    
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Solution</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: i use margin to align my div on right side if i remove this margin it will float on left side

Comment: you have to align your menu in right side right? logo in left side otherthan above output is okay. correct.